# Sending CloudWatch Alarms to Slack

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I configured a AWS lamdba function to sent messages to slack.  The lambda function works when I test it using SNS.  But when the cloud watch alarm triggers the SNS message, I get the email, but never received the slack  message.

I think it must be a permissions error for cloud watch, but I am not sure where I would need to update these permissions

Comment: When you successfully test the Lambda function using SNS are you using the same SNS topic that CloudWatch is sending alert messages to?

Comment: yes I am using the same sns notification

Comment: So you have an email subscription to the SNS topic, and your Lambda function is also subscribed to the same SNS topic. When CloudWatch posts to that topic you get the email, correct? If that's the case then CloudWatch has all the permissions it needs. Are you sure the Lambda function isn't erroring out?

Comment: When I go to SNS and publish a message from there, the message does pop up in slack.

Comment: And you're posting that to the same SNS topic that CloudWatch is posting to? If so, then you need to look into your Lambda function logs to see what errors may be occurring.

Comment: you can also use marbot.io it should be easier to use than your own lambda function...